# Classification of the singularities of $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ at $a=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I have to classify the singularities of $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ at $a=1$ and compute the radius of convergence of his power serie at the point $a$.

Is it possible to proceed without using the Laurent serie directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring,
$$ \frac{1}{z^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}
$$
By definition, $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$ if there exists a function $g$ that is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ with $g(z_0) \neq 0$ such that
$$ (z-z_0)^m f(z) = g(z)
$$
so at $z_0 = -i$, we can choose $m = 1$, $g(z) = \frac{1}{z-i}$. This shows that $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0 = -i$, and likewise for $z_0 = +i$.

If you let the centre of the power series be $a = 1$, since the function $\frac{1}{z^2 + 1}$ is holomorphic in the disk centred at $a$ with radius $\sqrt{2}$, the series should have radius of convergence of $\sqrt{2}$, by  Laurent's theorem.

Comment: How with Laurent's theorem did you conclude that the radius of convergence is $\sqrt{2}$? In using the theorem http://www.math.utsc.utoronto.ca/c34/chap6.pdf, I don't know how you use this theorem to conclude the radius of convergence.

Comment: @george Because the function is holomorphic inside the annulus centred at $a$ with inner radius 0 and outer radius $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @george It is the distance between $a$ and the poles.

Comment: @george Yes. It is basically the maximum radius you can find for which the function is holomorphic inside.

Comment: Thank you, I will now do my best to make the remaining numbers of myself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37879/discussion-between-henry-w-and-george).